# is it possible to get the address of function defined in the static library in windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, static-libraries, static-linking

Is there any way to get the address of the function which is defined in static library (.lib) which is been linked to some application .

Thanks

Comment: By some application you mean your application or some other application that you know has been linked against a static library?

Comment: some other application that i know has been linked against library

Comment: If the program was built in debug mode and you have access to the debug information (.pdb file, etc) then yes, you can locate a function by name. But if you don't have access to debug information then no, all statically linked function names have been removed from the program.

Comment: say i know there is function A() defined in the sample.lib. cant i get the address of A() without the help of .pdb as u mentioned ?

Comment: No, just having a lib doesn't tell you where the linker put it. Unless you have access to the files the developer had, you cannot find the address of a statically-linked function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A static library is nothing but an archive (like a .ZIP file) of object files.

When you link against a static library the linker will check which of these object files are needed and link them to the executable. The result is exactly the same as if you directly compiled the source code of the library in your project.

So the actual question is: Is it possible to find out the address of a non-static function in an executable file?

Some linkers (like GNU) generate a symbol table by default even in a project without debugging information. You could parse the symbol table in this case. However many linkers do not create this symbol table. In this case the information of all function names is lost so you do not have any chance to get information about the address without debugging information.